# Image is not getting displayed from base.html in few pages in django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a base.html which i extends to other pages also. In few pages , images are displayed but in few it does not. other than images , everything like header , section are displayed.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
some more --like header , section 
<footer>
<div id="footer">
    {% block footer %}
        <a href="https://github.com/shanker4999"> <img src ="../../static/blog/images/git.png"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2016 shankar.</p>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

My template file

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<h1>Articles for {{ year }}</h1>

{% for article in article_list %}
<h4><a href="/blog/{{article.id}}/">{{ article.headline }}</a></h4>
<h5>Posted by <strong>{{ article.reporter }}</strong>
                 on {{article.pub_date|date:"F j, Y"}}</h5><hr/>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

url `
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'article/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive, name='year_archive'),
    url(r'article/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive, name='month_archive'),
    url(r'(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.article_detail,name='article_detail'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$' ,views.comment,name='comment'),
    url(r'^contact',views.contact,name='contact'),
```

]`
views

```
ef year_archive(request,year):
#year=str(pub_date)[0:4]
year=year
try:
    article_list = Article.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
except Article.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Article does not Exists")
context = {'year':year, 'article_list':article_list}
return render(request, 'blog/year_archive.html',context)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not using the correct src. You should let the static function handle the static files. When the url changes `../../` will not be correct anymore, depending on the path.

You should configure the static directory in your settings.py file and then reference your image like this:

```
<img src ="{% static 'blog/images/git.png' %}"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're loading `staticfiles` but you never actually use it, you should use the [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:templatetag-staticfiles-static) template tag

```
"../../static/blog/images/git.png"
```

should be

```
{% static 'blog/images/git.png' %}
```

<sub>You should also use the url template tag..</sub>